# Unet: Spawning other objects with client authority

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am in the process of making a simple tic tac-tac-toe game using the new Unet functionality in Unity to learn how to use the Unet functions.

I have a brain code that spawns the 9 sprites to make up the board and am working on having these set to x's when clicked. I use a [synchvar] to keep track of the state of the sprites and and a hook to change the image when the `[SyncVar]` changes. The game works perfectly if I am controlling the server but does nothing if I am controlling the client. From what I understand you correct this by adding local player authority to the object and using [command] but this doesn't seem to correct the issue. The code below is what is attached to my sprites. The question has been answered and the code below reflects the correction.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;


public class spacescript : NetworkBehaviour {
    public Sprite x;
    public Sprite o;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    public int state;
    NetworkIdentity myNetId;

    void Awake ()
    {

        myNetId = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();

    }

    public void setstate(int newstate)
    {
        state=newstate;

        if (state == 1) 
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = x;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

        GameObject whatplayer = braincode.singleton.GetComponent<braincode> ().returnplayer();
        whatplayer.GetComponent<playerscript> ().thingwasclicked (myNetId, gameObject);


    }




}
```

my tiles are spawned by the following code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class braincode : NetworkBehaviour {
    public GameObject spaceprefab;
    static public braincode singleton;

    GameObject players;
    public static GameObject brain;
    void Start ()
    {

        singleton = this;
        brain = gameObject;
    }
    public GameObject  returnplayer()
    {
        return players;
    }
    public void add_player(GameObject player)
    {

        players = player;


    }
    public override void OnStartServer()
    {

        for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<3; y++) {

                GameObject  space = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(spaceprefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                space.transform.position = new Vector3 (-3 + (2 * x), -3+ (2*y), 0f);
                NetworkServer.Spawn (space);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and my playerobjects have the following code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class playerscript : NetworkBehaviour {


    void Start () 
    {


        if (isLocalPlayer) 
        {

            braincode.brain.GetComponent<braincode> ().add_player (gameObject);

        }
    }

    public void thingwasclicked(NetworkIdentity tiles , GameObject whoclicked)
    {
        Cmdassignstate (tiles,whoclicked);
    }

    [Command]
    public void Cmdassignstate(NetworkIdentity tile, GameObject whoclicked)

    {

        RpcUpdateState (1,whoclicked);

    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcUpdateState(int newState, GameObject tile)
    {
        tile.GetComponent<spacescript> ().setstate (1);

    }




}
```

Comment: StackOverflow allows answering your own question, if you're so inclined.

Comment: thanks again for all the help user3071284